# How to create glowing effect with HTML 5

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-animations

Looking for help implementing that little blue dot as seen on Stacks new Documentation site, it's perfect for animating a dashboard I'm building that shows service health/metrics. I grabbed html/css using Chrome's inspector, but I'm terrible at this stuff, I can't even get a dot, much less a blue one that glows ;-D

https://jsfiddle.net/raffinyc/3trup2c1/

```
.help-bubble:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #3af;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
}
<span class="help-bubble-outer-dot">
        <span class="help-bubble-inner-dot"></span>
</span>
```

[image]

Comment: you can look into this: https://codepen.io/nickpettit/pen/vacDI

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what I'm looking for, thx

Comment: another example in here http://jsfiddle.net/dH6LS/1667/ if you need more help, I can help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here's the full reproduction](https://jsfiddle.net/3trup2c1/1/). The animation makes liberal use of pseudoelements. The CSS:

```
.help-bubble .help-bubble-outer-dot {
    margin: 1px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0,149,255,0.4);
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: help-bubble-pulse 1.5s linear infinite;
}

.help-bubble {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 40px;
  top: 40px;
}

.help-bubble::after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #3af;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
}

.help-bubble .help-bubble-inner-dot {
    background-position: absolute;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0,149,255,0.4);
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: help-bubble-pulse 1.5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: help-bubble-pulse 1.5s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: help-bubble-pulse 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation: help-bubble-pulse 1.5s linear infinite;
}

.help-bubble .help-bubble-inner-dot:after {
    content: "";
    background-position: absolute;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0,149,255,0.4);
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: help-bubble-pulse 1.5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: help-bubble-pulse 1.5s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: help-bubble-pulse 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation: help-bubble-pulse 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes help-bubble-pulse{
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: .75;
  }
  25% {
    transform:scale(1);
    opacity:.75;
  }
  100% {
    transform:scale(2.5);
    opacity:0
  }
}
```

For the record, I'm not very well versed in code intellectual property but it's unlikely you have the rights to use this exactly without somehow making it your own.

Comment: on the money, very nice, and for the record, no intention of using this code as-is; just wanted to see how it was implemented, the code sample cuts out all the noise and makes learning the technique much easier for me, that was really my goal.

Comment: @ZiedRebhi
`
.help-bubble {
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try `box-shadow`:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,225,255,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,225,255,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,225,255,1);
```

The syntax is:

```
0px (horizontal offset) 0px (vertical offset) 20px (bur value) 0px (spread value) rgba (color value)
```

See here for more information:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Comment: Not quite there, appears to be shadow only, I'm looking for glowing effect, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation